# In Hammer 3.4 where do I find the 'null' texure?

Tags: level-design, hammer

I'm using Valve's Hammer Editor v3.4 to make maps for Counter-Strike 1.6.  I want to learn to use the 'null' texture to optimize my map by not drawing surfaces the player won't see, but when I search for it in the list of textures, I don't see it.  I'm guessing I'm not loading some WAD that I need, but I'm not sure which one it is.

Comment: [Does this method not work in your version](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=299236)?

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you, that answers my question.  If you want to post it as an answer I'll accept / upvote it.  I didn't have zhlt.wad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Doing a quick search for "hammer null texture" yields this thread as the very first result](https://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?t=299236). There, user KliPPy says:

> You can find null (and other special textures) in zhlt.wad, by downloading [Zoner's Half-Life Tools](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/ZHLT).

Please remember to search for your keywords when you have a game dev question - you might be surprised how many great answers are already out there!